# Debugging Vue 3 with Vue CLI V4

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vuejs3, vue-cli-4

I'm using Vue 3 and I want to debug the standard Vue demo using VS Code (Chrome Extension Debugger).
My vue.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'
    }
}
```

Here are my launch.json settings:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "vuejs: chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "breakOnLoad": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

When starting the debugger, I can only debug the compiled app.js and not the HelloWorld.vue. To me it looks like the source map is not being built. Can someone help me with this problem?

[Component to debug (components/Hello World.vue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGGd.png)

[Debugged compiled app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHQns.png)

If it's necessary:

- Node Version: 15.11.0
- Vue-CLI Version: 4.5.11

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue. I'm not sure where to report it, but a workaround I found is adding "debugger" seems to work until there's a fix. (My launch.json and vue config is the same as yours.)

[image]